# Deduce function f from integral

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives

I do not understand how to perform this exercise:

> If $f$ is a continuous function such that:$$\int_0^xf(t)\ dt=(x-1)e^{2x}+\int_0^xe^{-t}f(t) \ dt$$ For all $x$, what function $f$ results?

Comment: Take the derivative w.r.t. $x$ and you'll get an equation that you can solve for $f$.

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: @MontyHall see my answer, the function is not defined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function $f$, since letting $x=0$ on both sides of the given equation yields $0=-1$.

---

(Notice that using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to solve for $f$ yields

$\hspace .3 in \displaystyle f(x)=\frac{e^{3x}(2x-1)}{e^x-1}$, and both integrals diverge for this function.)

Comment: To clarify: since $\lim _{x \to 0} \frac {\Bbb e ^x - 1} x = 1$, it follows that for every $r>0$ the integral $\int _0 ^r f \ \Bbb d x$ has the same behaviour as $\int _0 ^r \frac 1 x \ \Bbb d x$, which is divergent.